# SQL Server Trigger After Insert is Repeating old valus

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

Can someone please explain why this trigger would start failing and insert the same record repeatedly? It seems as though there is something wrong with the variables. The purpose of the trigger is to copy the inserted record from the Employee table to the EmployeeHistory table. I set the trigger and it runs fine.  But then when my coworker runs some insert scripts, it starts repeating the same old value from my last execution of an insert, instead of the new values that they are trying to insert.

I have already recoded this to not use variables, but I would still like to know why this doesn't work as expected.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[triggerEmployee_AfterInsert]
       ON [dbo].[Employee]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
       SET NOCOUNT ON;
 
       DECLARE @EmployeeID varchar(25)
       DECLARE @FirstName varchar(25)
       DECLARE @LastName varchar(50)
       DECLARE @FullName varchar(75)
       DECLARE @EmailAddress varchar(50)
       DECLARE @ManagerID varchar(15)
       DECLARE @JobTitle varchar(50)
       DECLARE @EmployeeStatus varchar(10)
       DECLARE @Office varchar(25)

 
       SELECT @EmployeeID = [dbo].[Employee].[EmployeeID]
            ,@FirstName = [dbo].[Employee].[FirstName]
            ,@LastName = [dbo].[Employee].[LastName]
            ,@FullName = [dbo].[Employee].[FullName]
            ,@EmailAddress = [dbo].[Employee].[EmailAddress]
            ,@ManagerID = [dbo].[Employee].[ManagerID]
            ,@JobTitle = [dbo].[Employee].[JobTitle]
            ,@EmployeeStatus = [dbo].[Employee].[EmployeeStatus]
            ,@Office = [dbo].[Employee].[Office]
       FROM [dbo].[Employee]
 
       INSERT INTO [dbo].[EmployeeHistory] (
            EmployeeID
            ,FirstName
            ,LastName
            ,FullName
            ,EmailAddress
            ,ManagerID
            ,JobTitle
            ,EmployeeStatus
            ,Office
       )
       VALUES (
            @EmployeeID
            ,@FirstName
            ,@LastName
            ,@FullName
            ,@EmailAddress
            ,@ManagerID
            ,@JobTitle
            ,@EmployeeStatus
            ,@Office
       )
END
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employee] ENABLE TRIGGER [triggerEmployee_AfterInsert]
GO
```

[image: Image of table with repeated values]

Comment: `start failing` -> well, this could never have worked, because you're just grabbing an arbitrary row from the table (`SELECT @var = ... FROM dbo.Employee;`). The trigger should referenced `inserted` pseudo-table and should _not_ make the false assumption that a trigger fires _per row_. Even when you fix the source of the change your code currently will not properly handle a multi-row insert of any kind.

Comment: Your trigger doesn't use the *Inserted* table, so how do you expect it to do anything with the "inserted" rows? You are basically select a single row at random.

Comment: Probably [this article](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/) would be a worthwhile read.

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting the SELECT statement to use the INSERTED table fixed the issue.

```
       SELECT @EmployeeID = [EmployeeID]
            ,@FirstName = [FirstName]
            ,@LastName = [LastName]
            ,@FullName = [FullName]
            ,@EmailAddress = [EmailAddress]
            ,@ManagerID = [ManagerID]
            ,@JobTitle = [JobTitle]
            ,@EmployeeStatus = [EmployeeStatus]
            ,@Office = [Office]
       FROM INSERTED
```

Comment: *Fixed* is not technically true, what happens when you insert several rows in a single batch? You should be doing `insert into... select from inserted`. Also just FYI, SQL Server has full support for historical data out of the box, known as Temporal Tables.